# Handle multiple csv import request parallel and efficiently

Tags: php, csv

I will have to import data in CSV from database, there can be over 100k records to import. Cron will be based on each user reoccurence time like after 2,3,4 hours and it will pick data from database and import in CSV and send to customer. At one time, I could have multiple requests to import data in csv and send to customer.

As parallel processing directly is not allowed in PHP so I searched some method that I can use like

- Multi curl request
- Gearman
- pcntl
- Threading

But I am not getting which method would be efficient and easy to implement? I am trying to make logic so that all users get their CSVs on time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can configure your php interpreter instance, good idea is use that library [thread](https://packagist.org/packages/amphp/thread).

Multi curl request seems to be lowest option.

Pcntl also requires configure php interpreter instance.

Comment: Ok. I check Thread. Any idea what could be drawback of using this?

Comment: Installing unofficiall php extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php). I using it in many projects and didn't found inconveniences. There is many other libraries wrapping that module. In my opinion it's fast and clear soultion.

Comment: Maybe one: "pthreads requires a build of PHP with ZTS (Zend Thread Safety) "

Comment: Ok I am working on it. As soon as I understand this. Will notify here